# Same rest endpoint with different PathVariable

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm trying to make two rest endpoint with same uri but different types. 
The first would search by EAN (Int) the second one would search by id (String). Could I overload somehow the endpoint? I use Spring Boot with Kotlin

```
@GetMapping("/book/{ean}")
fun getABookByEan(@PathVariable ean: Int) : ResponseEntity<*> {
    repository.getByEan(ean)?.let {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(it)
    }
    throw ItemNotFoundException()
}

@GetMapping("/book/{id}")
fun getABookById(@PathVariable id: String) : ResponseEntity<*> {
    repository.getById(id)?.let {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(it)
    }
    throw ItemNotFoundException()
}
```

After this I got an exception that multiple methods are mapped for the same endpoint.

...NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path...

Comment: You should create two mappings for that `/book/byEan/{ean}` and `/book/byId/{id}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found out that the only way to do it is regex if I want to stick to my API.

```
@GetMapping("/book/{ean:[\\d]+}")

@GetMapping("/book/{id:^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$}")
```

With it the MongoDB generated hexadecimal 24 character can be differentiated from the simple numbers. If anyone find a better way let me know in comments.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do it on mapping level. Probably you should try paths  like:

```
/book/ean/{ean}
/book/id/{id}
```

Alternatively just

```
/book/id/{someUniversalId}
```

then distinguish between different kinds of ids in your executable code.

Comment: This is not in context of question. different url should work.. The question was same endpoint with different path variable.

Answer (score 0):

From HTTP point of view it is the same endpoint as it is a text based protocol and path parameter is always a string. Thus, Spring throws an exception.

To deal with the issue you can either identify argument type inside method body:

```
@GetMapping("/book/{identifier}")
fun getABookById(@PathVariable identifier: String) : ResponseEntity<*> {
    try {
        val id = identifier.toInt()
        // id case
        repository.getById(id)?.let {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(it)
        }
    } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
        // ean case
        repository.getByEan(identifier)?.let {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(it)
        }
    }
    throw ItemNotFoundException()
}
```

or pass ean or id as @RequestParam like /book?ean=abcdefg, /book?id=5.

Comment: Using try/catch for flow is a bad idea. This use case is already supported via the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

It would be beneficial to develop a query filter / query criteria, to process something like:

```
/book?q=ean+eq+abcdefg (meaning ean=abcdefg)
/book?q=id+gt+1000  (meaning id>1000)
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

How about using matrix parameters?

So for id, you can use path parameter - `/books/{id}`

and for ean, matrix parameter - `/books;ean={ean}`

In fact, for id too you can use matrix parameter - `/books;{id}` or `/books;id={id}`

The general url for matrix parameters - `/{resource-name}[;{selector}]/`

source - Apigee REST API design best practices